# Female representations of Satan

Tags: christianity

Most folkloric representations of the Devil seem to be male. For example, (female) witches were sometimes imagined to have had carnal knowledge of Satan. In most folktales about the devil, said entity is depicted either as an animal, an inhuman creature of some sort, or a  man.  Are there any mythological or folkloric examples of Satan appearing in a specifically human, female form?

Comment: 'Satan' per se is a figure of Judeo-Christian-Islamic tradition. Would you accept a response from outside that tradition?

Comment: @Spencer - You mean some other god of evil, adversary, or trickster spirit? Not really. I'm sure there's some such entity that's even exclusively female, but that's not really what I'm wondering.

Comment: @Gibet - Certainly. Even back in Medieval times and earlier, theologians would tell you that the devil was a formless spirit, but the Devil often was depicted as *assuming* the form of a man, or a serpent, or a horned humanoid, or whatever. So the form of a woman would roughly be on equal footing.

Answer (score 1):

From Jacob Grimm “*Deutsche Mythologie*,” translated by James Stallybrass Vol 3, 1883, page 1007:

> Judaism has devils, but knows nothing of she-devils; all power for good or evil it places in the hands of male beings (page 396). To put it still more generally: gods are all together the older, and a strict monotheism or dualism recognizes gods alone; it is in the mellower fullness of Polytheism that goddesses first emerge. The Teutonic paganism, like others, is fond of female deities and elves: even the Goth. Vaihts (genius) is feminine (page 439). Divine mothers, bright benignant dames, norns, valkyrs, wood-wives, water-maidens, formed a main part of the religion: only kobolds and home-sprites are exclusively male; the very giantess are often lovely in mien and manners, and the world of the dead is ruled by a goddess.

He goes on to describe Grendel’s mother in Beowulf and Devil’s mothers/grandmothers in the KHM.

His mythology is very worthwhile reading. Luckily, it has been translated into English so it can be read by Americans also. The Stallybrass text are available free online.

The problem in answering the question further is that many people think that that "Satan," the "Devil," "Lucifer," etc., all refer to the same being/idea when they are not. In different times/places characters are replaced. For example, in the Grimms KHM, the character that often appears as the "Teufel" (devil) was at one time prior Donar (Thunar/Thorr). It is Donar who is the god who rules over clouds and rain and when the text describe the Devil arriving with wind and noise, this was at one time how Donar arrived. Time passed and Donar was replaced with the Devil. But elements of wind and noise in the text still point to the older pagan beliefs. This “Devil” here is not necessarily the same being as the Jewish “Statan.”

Note- it was easier to use the Stallybrass text rather than translate the whole thing myself again

Comment: Why are you talking about Jewish representations of Satan here, specifically? I was more interested in Christian (although Muslim would also work).

Comment: And your quote about Judaism is not correct. *The* most famous she-devil, Lilith, is heavily tied to Jewish tradition. It also seems to think polytheism is newer than monotheism. ..which is odd.

Comment: If you want to discuss this in [chat], feel free.

Comment: This is what Grimm wrote about the subject. Sorry if it is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Grimm does not seem to classify Littlith as a devil. He mentions her in a section under creation as a rabinnical myth as the first woman created in the same way as Adam from the earth.

Comment: Lilith isn’t the *Devil*, no. And she’s not what I am looking for here. But she’s a devil *figure*. She represents a similar archetype. Looking at what Jacob writes afterward, he seems to be talking about female folkloric figures in general. He talks about Grendel’s mother, for instance.

Comment: That’s why he says, “…all power for good or evil it places in the hands of male beings.” And that’s what my comment responds to, since there is no doubt that the folkloric Lilith possesses power (for evil). Then, also, the conception of God and angels, though often associated with male pronouns and stereotypically masculine attributes, has been that God lacks human gender for much longer than people realize. You seem to be an expert on the works of Grimm, but one needs to look much further than that for a full accounting of gender in Judaism (or indeed Christianity).

Comment: Also, the Kabbalistic tradition, a form of Jewish mysticism with heavy influence on European Jewish thought from the 1300s onward (was Grimm familiar with this?) speaks of the Shekhinah, or female Divine Presence, the female aspect of God. Now, I’m not going to deny that there’s a long vein of marginalization of women in monotheistic traditions, but polytheistic traditions can experience the same problem, and things (as they generally are) are much more complicated.

Comment: And even the Biblical Eve herself (Chava), though often vilified in Jewish and Christian thought alike, must certainly be said to have possessed power. The traditional conception is that, by choosing to eat the fruit of the Tree of Knowledge of Good and Evil, she lost humanity’s immortality and closeness to God.

Comment: Sorry, I can only tell you what Grimm wrote about it. His book is specific to German mythology, but he also looks at many other sources and ideas. Feel free to disagree with Grimm if you are more knowledgeable on the subject than he was. I am only passing on what he wrote about it. What he wrote was written in the 19th century. Modern scholarship might have new and different ideas. Maybe someone else with more knowledge of the subject can answer the question then.

Comment: Shekhinah - I don't know. There is no entry with that spelling in the books. The source was listed above, so you can look if there is anything useful for you there if you like. His sections on the Devil, Gods, Godesses, etc., is extensive.